# Validation of the Apple Store receipt fails

Tags: app-store, mac-app-store

I wrote the code that allows my application to validate the receipt issued by the Apple Store. For the moment, the application doesn’t have a receipt. I have a valid distribution provisioning profile.

When I launch the application, it exits with a status of 173 of course.

Subsequently, the system requests my Apple ID and password but they are not recognized. Should I create an account on Itunes Connect before I can receive a valid receipt ?

Comment: it's a hassle. and badly documented. feel free to improve my answer when you succeeded to check.

Answer (score 0):

check your profiling and code signatures. when signed "developer" or "debug" then AppStore will ask for a so called sandbox user. and yes, you create this userid(s) in iTunes connect > users > create test user.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this solution and I'll keep you informed.